# How to gain access to a <webview>'s window object

Tags: javascript, webview, electron

With electron, a `<webview>` is used instead of an `<iframe>` due to security concerns regarding framing. However, it would be incredibly useful to still have access to the webview's process from it's outer owned process. Is this possible, to modify the DOM or attach handlers that are closed to the outer DOM?

Comment: What do you mean with outer process and outer DOM? outer process = main part and "inner" process = webview (renderer)? Maybe you need the IPC feature https://electron.atom.io/docs/api/ipc-main/ https://electron.atom.io/docs/api/ipc-renderer/

Comment: Well, that's the correct terminology I intended, but my goal here is to modify the DOM of an _arbitrary website_, not one that I've coded myself. Very cool tech though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add custom code and change the DOM of arbitrary websites, add this to your `index.html`:

```
<webview preload="./yourscript.js" src="http://yourpage.com" style="position:absolute;width:100%;height:100%;"></webview>
```

Here is a detailed documentation: https://electron.atom.io/docs/api/webview-tag/

Here is an github issue I've found about this topic: https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/2048#issuecomment-115092053